# How to extract date from a string?

Tags: python

I have this weird string:

```
'": "1899-12-30 14:50:00.000"": " "'
```

I need to just extract the date.
I have looked at all the different python string manipulation functions but I just can't seem to find one that works for this interesting format.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your previous attempt at meeting the requirement you've described as a [mre]? This seems like something that was improperly extracted from a broader structured document, the real answer here is likely to fix your upstream dataflow to not mangle the data itself.

Comment: @esqew You are correct - and I will address that soon -- just needed a quick fix for a POC. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to extract the date as a sting or as a `datetime` object (i.e. a *real* Python date).

Comment: "I have looked at all the different python string manipulation functions but I just can't seem to find one that works for this interesting format." Well, what is the *rule that tells you* where the date starts and where the date ends? What *algorithm* would you follow in order to solve the problem by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your string if you just want `1899-12-30` you could do:

```
'": "1899-12-30 14:50:00.000"": " "'.split(' ')[1][1:]
```

if you want the full `1899-12-30 14:50:00.000` you could do

```
'": "1899-12-30 14:50:00.000"": " "'.split('"')[2]
```

#### Explanation:

taking the string we are splitting the string by its characters in the first example a space and in the second a double quote as those characters surround the date element. The split function creates a list in which we access the element that we would like in the first case the second element (0 index list) while the second list we grab the third element. For the first Example printing out the output before we do a slice of the sting would give an extra double quote before the date, therefore we take the first element off of the string to only get the date.

Comment: Thank you - now I just need to understand it :-)

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution:

```
mys = '": "1899-12-30 14:50:00.000"": " "'
print(mys.strip('": "'))
```

Comment: That works too - thank you. Hmmm ... I tried "split" and not "strip"